i am not able to connect to ble device,where is the problem in my mainactivity.java code can somebody help me fix it?
this is mainactivity.java that is in android studio.
package com.example.bleapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.clj.fastble.BleManager;
import com.clj.fastble.callback.BleGattCallback;
import com.clj.fastble.callback.BleNotifyCallback;
import com.clj.fastble.callback.BleScanCallback;
import com.clj.fastble.data.BleDevice;
import com.clj.fastble.exception.BleException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 2;

    private TextView statusTextView;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Button scanButton;
    private BleDeviceAdapter adapter;

    private BleDevice connectedDevice;
    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic readCharacteristic;

    // Replace with your ESP32 BLE characteristic UUIDs
    private static final UUID SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    private static final UUID CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = UUID.fromString("0000fef4-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        statusTextView = findViewById(R.id.statusTextView);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        scanButton = findViewById(R.id.scanButton);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new BleDeviceAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        BleManager.getInstance().init(getApplication());

        scanButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (checkPermissions()) {
                startScan();
            }
        });

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this::connectToDevice);
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        if (!BleManager.getInstance().isBlueEnable()) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE), REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            return false;
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void startScan() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }

        BleManager.getInstance().scan(new BleScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanStarted(boolean success) {
                scanButton.setEnabled(false);
                statusTextView.setText("Scanning...");
                Log.d(TAG, "Scan started");
            }

            @Override
            public void onScanning(BleDevice bleDevice) {
                adapter.addDevice(bleDevice);
                Log.d(TAG, "Device found: " + bleDevice.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onScanFinished(List<BleDevice> scanResultList) {
                scanButton.setEnabled(true);
                statusTextView.setText("Scan finished.");
                Log.d(TAG, "Scan finished with " + scanResultList.size() + " devices found");
            }
        });
    }

    private void connectToDevice(BleDevice device) {
        BleManager.getInstance().cancelScan();
        BleManager.getInstance().connect(device, new BleGattCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStartConnect() {
                statusTextView.setText("Connecting...");
                Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to " + device.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectFail(BleDevice bleDevice, BleException exception) {
                statusTextView.setText("Connect fail: " + exception.toString());
                Log.e(TAG, "Connection failed: " + exception.getDescription());
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectSuccess(BleDevice bleDevice, BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                statusTextView.setText("Connected");
                Log.d(TAG, "Connected to " + bleDevice.getName());

                // Save connected device
                connectedDevice = bleDevice;

                // Discover services and characteristics
                try {
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisConnected(boolean isActiveDisConnected, BleDevice device, BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                statusTextView.setText("Disconnected");
                connectedDevice = null;
                Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected from " + device.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(SERVICE_UUID);
                    if (service != null) {
                        readCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);
                        enableNotification(readCharacteristic);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Service and characteristics found");
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Service not found");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Service discovery failed with status: " + status);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void enableNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        BleManager.getInstance().notify(
                connectedDevice,
                characteristic.getService().getUuid().toString(),
                characteristic.getUuid().toString(),
                new BleNotifyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNotifySuccess() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Notification setup successful for characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNotifyFailure(BleException exception) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to set up notification for characteristic " + characteristic.getUuid() + ": " + exception.getDescription());
                        // Handle failure scenario, e.g., retry or display error to the user
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCharacteristicChanged(byte[] data) {
                        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                            String hexString = bytesToHex(data);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Hex data received: " + hexString);
                            String jsonData = hexToString(hexString);
                            updateLabel1(jsonData);
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Received empty data for characteristic " + characteristic.getUuid());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateLabel1(String jsonData) {
        try {
            // Parse JSON data
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            double temperature = jsonObject.getDouble("temperature");
            double humidity = jsonObject.getDouble("humidity");
            int no2 = jsonObject.getInt("no2");
            int c2h5oh = jsonObject.getInt("c2h5oh");
            int voc = jsonObject.getInt("voc");
            int co = jsonObject.getInt("co");
            int pm1 = jsonObject.getInt("pm1");
            int pm2_5 = jsonObject.getInt("pm2_5");
            int pm10 = jsonObject.getInt("pm10");

            // Update UI with parsed values
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp_value)).setText(String.valueOf(temperature));
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.hum_value)).setText(String.valueOf(humidity));
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.no2_value)).setText(String.valueOf(no2));
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.c2h5oh_value)).setText(String.valueOf(c2h5oh));
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.voc_value)).setText(String.valueOf(voc));
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.co_value)).setText(String.valueOf(co));
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.pm1_value)).setText(String.valueOf(pm1));
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.pm2_value)).setText(String.valueOf(pm2_5));
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.pm10_value)).setText(String.valueOf(pm10));
            });

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            hexString.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    }

    private String hexToString(String hex) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i += 2) {
            String str = hex.substring(i, i + 2);
            sb.append((char) Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startScan();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Location permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (connectedDevice != null) {
            BleManager.getInstance().disconnect(connectedDevice);
        }
        BleManager.getInstance().destroy();
    }
}

this my activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scanButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Scan" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="387dp"
        android:layout_height="156dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statusTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Status: "
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_width="381dp"
        android:layout_height="81dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Text for Label1" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="temp" android:padding="4dp"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/temp_value" android:text="000" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@android:color/black" android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="hum." android:padding="4dp"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/hum_value" android:text="000" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@android:color/black" android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="NO2" android:padding="4dp"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/no2_value" android:text="000" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@android:color/black" android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="C2H5OH" android:padding="4dp"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/c2h5oh_value" android:text="000" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@android:color/black" android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="VOC" android:padding="4dp"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/voc_value" android:text="000" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@android:color/black" android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="CO" android:padding="4dp"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/co_value" android:text="000" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@android:color/black" android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="PM1" android:padding="4dp"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/pm1_value" android:text="000" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@android:color/black" android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="PM2" android:padding="4dp"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/pm2_value" android:text="000" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@android:color/black" android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="PM10" android:padding="4dp"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/pm10_value" android:text="000" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@android:color/black" android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="TEST" android:padding="4dp"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/test_value" android:text="000" android:padding="4dp" android:background="@android:color/black" android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>

u can see my build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.bleapp'
    compileSdk 34
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bleapp"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        customDebugType {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1' // Updated androidx.recyclerview dependency
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])



}

this is link where u can find jar file for app/libs: text
i tried this code in my android studio but can't get the hex string in my android application.the below code is uploaded into esp32s3 to advertise a static hex string.
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/event_groups.h"
#include "esp_event.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "esp_nimble_hci.h"
#include "nimble/nimble_port.h"
#include "nimble/nimble_port_freertos.h"
#include "host/ble_hs.h"
#include "services/gap/ble_svc_gap.h"
#include "services/gatt/ble_svc_gatt.h"
#include "sdkconfig.h"

char *TAG = "ipollusense";
uint8_t ble_addr_type;
void ble_app_advertise(void);

// Write data to ESP32 defined as server
static int device_write(uint16_t conn_handle, uint16_t attr_handle, struct ble_gatt_access_ctxt *ctxt, void *arg)
{
    // printf("Data from the client: %.*s\n", ctxt->om->om_len, ctxt->om->om_data);

    char * data = (char *)ctxt->om->om_data;
    printf("%d\n",strcmp(data, (char *)"LIGHT ON")==0);
    if (strcmp(data, (char *)"LIGHT ON\0")==0)
    {
       printf("LIGHT ON\n");
    }
    else if (strcmp(data, (char *)"LIGHT OFF\0")==0)
    {
        printf("LIGHT OFF\n");
    }
    else if (strcmp(data, (char *)"FAN ON\0")==0)
    {
        printf("FAN ON\n");
    }
    else if (strcmp(data, (char *)"FAN OFF\0")==0)
    {
        printf("FAN OFF\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Data from the client: %.*s\n", ctxt->om->om_len, ctxt->om->om_data);
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}

// Read data from ESP32 defined as server
static int device_read(uint16_t con_handle, uint16_t attr_handle, struct ble_gatt_access_ctxt *ctxt, void *arg)
{
    const char *response = "{\"temperature\":25.40,\"humidity\":39.80,\"no2\":17,\"c2h5oh\":136,\"voc\":10,\"co\":55,\"pm1\":49,\"pm2_5\":67,\"pm10\":94}";
    os_mbuf_append(ctxt->om, response, strlen(response));
    return 0;
}

// Array of pointers to other service definitions
// UUID - Universal Unique Identifier
static const struct ble_gatt_svc_def gatt_svcs[] = {
    {.type = BLE_GATT_SVC_TYPE_PRIMARY,
     .uuid = BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(0x1800),                 // Define UUID for device type
     .characteristics = (struct ble_gatt_chr_def[]){
         {.uuid = BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(0xFEF4),           // Define UUID for reading
          .flags = BLE_GATT_CHR_F_READ,
          .access_cb = device_read},
         {.uuid = BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(0xDEAD),           // Define UUID for writing
          .flags = BLE_GATT_CHR_F_WRITE,
          .access_cb = device_write},
         {0}}},
    {0}};

// BLE event handling
static int ble_gap_event(struct ble_gap_event *event, void *arg)
{
    switch (event->type)
    {
    // Advertise if connected
    case BLE_GAP_EVENT_CONNECT:
        ESP_LOGI("GAP", "BLE GAP EVENT CONNECT %s", event->connect.status == 0 ? "OK!" : "FAILED!");
        if (event->connect.status != 0)
        {
            ble_app_advertise();
        }
        break;
    // Advertise again after completion of the event
    case BLE_GAP_EVENT_DISCONNECT:
        ESP_LOGI("GAP", "BLE GAP EVENT DISCONNECTED");
        {
            ble_app_advertise();
        }
        break;
    case BLE_GAP_EVENT_ADV_COMPLETE:
        ESP_LOGI("GAP", "BLE GAP EVENT");
        ble_app_advertise();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Define the BLE connection
void ble_app_advertise(void)
{
    // GAP - device name definition
    struct ble_hs_adv_fields fields;
    const char *device_name;
    memset(&fields, 0, sizeof(fields));
    device_name = ble_svc_gap_device_name(); // Read the BLE device name
    fields.name = (uint8_t *)device_name;
    fields.name_len = strlen(device_name);
    fields.name_is_complete = 1;
    ble_gap_adv_set_fields(&fields);

    // GAP - device connectivity definition
    struct ble_gap_adv_params adv_params;
    memset(&adv_params, 0, sizeof(adv_params));
    adv_params.conn_mode = BLE_GAP_CONN_MODE_UND; // connectable or non-connectable
    adv_params.disc_mode = BLE_GAP_DISC_MODE_GEN; // discoverable or non-discoverable
    ble_gap_adv_start(ble_addr_type, NULL, BLE_HS_FOREVER, &adv_params, ble_gap_event, NULL);
}

// The application
void ble_app_on_sync(void)
{
    ble_hs_id_infer_auto(0, &ble_addr_type); // Determines the best address type automatically
    ble_app_advertise();                     // Define the BLE connection
}

// The infinite task
void host_task(void *param)
{
    nimble_port_run(); // This function will return only when nimble_port_stop() is executed
}

void app_main()
{
    nvs_flash_init();                          // 1 - Initialize NVS flash using
    // esp_nimble_hci_and_controller_init();      // 2 - Initialize ESP controller
    nimble_port_init();                        // 3 - Initialize the host stack
    ble_svc_gap_device_name_set("ipollusense"); // 4 - Initialize NimBLE configuration - server name
    ble_svc_gap_init();                        // 4 - Initialize NimBLE configuration - gap service
    ble_svc_gatt_init();                       // 4 - Initialize NimBLE configuration - gatt service
    ble_gatts_count_cfg(gatt_svcs);            // 4 - Initialize NimBLE configuration - config gatt services
    ble_gatts_add_svcs(gatt_svcs);             // 4 - Initialize NimBLE configuration - queues gatt services.
    ble_hs_cfg.sync_cb = ble_app_on_sync;      // 5 - Initialize application
    nimble_port_freertos_init(host_task);      // 6 - Run the thread
}

i want hex string which is something like this {"temperature":25.40,"humidity":39.80,"no2":17,"c2h5oh":136,"voc":10,"co":55,"pm1":49,"pm2_5":67,"pm10":94} in label1 textview and then parse the values in their attribute_value or key_value textview inplace of 000.
